# Improper integral involving sinc function and Pochhammer symbol

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, pochhammer-symbol

Can anyone please advise me how to integrate expressions of the form $\text{sinc}\,(x) / (1-x)_n$ along the real axis?

Using a CAS, one could suggest that
$$
n! \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x (1-x)_n}dx=2^n,\ n=1,2,\ldots
$$
But I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: A few manipulations give the equivalent integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(1+n)}{\Gamma(1+t)\Gamma(1-t+n)}\mathrm dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \binom{n}{t}\mathrm dt$$

Comment: Thank you for the interesting observation, but how about integrals of binomial coefficients? Could you please suggest some source on how to integrate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using contour integration one can show that
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin \pi x}{x \cdot (1-x)\ldots (n-x)}dx\\
&=\text{Im}\left\{\pi i \left(\underset{z=0}{\text{res}}-\sum_{k=1}^n \underset{z=k}{\text{res}}\right)\frac{e^{\pi i z}}{z \cdot (1-z)\ldots (n-z)}\right\}\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{1}{n!}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k\cdot (1-k)\ldots (-1)\cdot 1\ldots (n-k)}\right)\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\right)=\frac{2^n\pi}{n!},\quad n=1,2,3\ldots
\end{align}